# Envio de foto com privacidade pública

Tags: android, facebook

Através do código abaixo, consigo enviar uma foto para as fotos do usuário que está logado, e a foto é enviada com sucesso.

Porém a foto vai com privacidade **Amigos**.

Como faço para enviar com privacidade **Público**?

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
/* make the API call */
params.putByteArray("source", byteArray); 
params.putString("caption", "Titulo");
params.putBoolean("published", true);

new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/photos", params, HttpMethod.POST, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
    }
}).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nível de privacidade (audência no SDK Android) é configurado quando o usuário autoriza a sua app com permissão de escrita e não pode ser mudado pelo seu aplicativo.

Quando você solicita permissão de escrita, você pode setar a audência desejada. Trecho do exemplo *RPSSample* que acompanha o SDK:

```
LoginManager.getInstance()
.setDefaultAudience(DefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
.logInWithPublishPermissions(RpsFragment.this, Arrays.asList(ADDITIONAL_PERMISSIONS));
```

O nível de audiência que você procura é o `DefaultAudience.EVERYONE`.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/DefaultAudience/

Comment: Perfeito, exatamente o que precisava. Obrigado!